# What is the difference between GWT Designer and WindowsBuilder Pro?

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

What is the difference between GWT Designer and WindowsBuilder Pro?  Both are avaialble in Open With... in the eclipse project pane...I am new to GWT, which is better to use?
Thanks
bob

Answer (score 1):

Windows Builder Pro was bought by google and now is called the GWT Designer